# What is the Chomsky type of the given language?

Tags: programming-languages, finite-automata

A grammar G generating language L is defined by:

G = ( {x,y}, {S,A,B,C}, P, S)

where the elements of P are:

S -> ABA

AB -> AC

CB -> BBC

CA -> BBA

A -> a | E

B -> b

Is the language L generated by G most accurately said to be:

A. Chomsky type 0

B. Chomsky type 1 (context sensitive)

C. Chomsky type 2 (context free)

D. Chomsky type 3 (regular)

E. None of the above

I think this is type 0 because it is not context sensitive. But I wonder this rules might be reduced to something else and becomes context sensitive or context free or so on. How to deal with this kind of question?

---

Grammar G is defined by:

G = ({a,b}, {S,A,B}, P, S)

where P is the set:

S -> AB | AS

A -> a | aA

B -> b | bb

Is the language L generated by G most accurately said to be:

A. Chomsky type 0

B. Chomsky type 1 (context sensitive)

C. Chomsky type 2 (context free)

D. Chomsky type 3 (regular)

E. None of the above

I think this is context free because LHS has one nonterminal. But I'm not sure because this rules might be reduced and becomes regular grammer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammar 1 is context-sensitive as written (unsure why you think it's not, as it matches the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Formal_definition) unambiguously). Grammar 2 is context-free as written.

Grammar 1's language looks to be `(a|E)b^k(a|E)` where k is in the form 2^i, i is a non-negative integer. This language appears to be context-sensitive.

Grammar 2's language looks to be `aa*(b|bb)`, which is regular.

Since the questions are asking about the languages, not the grammars as written, I would say that 1 is context-sensitive and 2 is regular.